# could model contains repository reference?

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

Could my domain model reference my repository interfaces? or better yet, containing my repositories definitions?

I ask because I was thinking about what I read on the limbo of internet that says that a model shouldn't know about its persistence, but I think if the repository exists due the model, I mean, to handle specific needs of its model, why not the model project define it?

Is it a problem/ bad design if I do the following?

```
public interface ISomethingThatNeedToBeAprovedRepository
{
   void Save(SomethingThatNeedToBeAproved somethingThatNeedToBeAproved);
}

public class SomethingThatNeedToBeAproved
{
    public int Status {get;set;}
    public string Reason {get;set;}

    public ISomethingThatNeedToBeAprovedRepository Repository{ get; set;}

    public void Aprove(status, reason)
    {
        DoSomeAsserts();
        Status = status;
        Reason = reason;

        Repository.save(this);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can!

At given point you need to persist your aggregate so a repository is needed. I use to take `IRepository` inside my domain model, while infratructure details of Repository in another project.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will be a bad design.
The domain model (this domain layer) should totally be independent of any other layer.
The repository interface and implementation should refer to the domain model to save and perform storage operations.

Comment: This is exactly what I said. The two things (domain layer and persistence layer) must be separated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is really it depends.

As @marianoc84 said, at some point, the application would really need to concern about persistence. The question here, is the particular domain model needs a concern about data persistence?
If it does, then it is make sense to put a repository inside the model.

On other side, having the repository inside 'may' makes unit test more challenging, and just be aware that generally speaking, the domain model could be distributed anywhere to pretty much up to application layer.

However, if the model does not really need to concern about persistence, then you don't really need a repository inside. The persistence could be done on other places such as having an 'ApprovalServices' which in this case, there could be several A, B, C, D and E that could be approved and have this to be persisted.